# Cocoapods: use_frameworks! causes linker errors

Tags: objective-c, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

I want to provide my Objective-C library as cocoapod and some users wants to get it with 'use_frameworks!' option. Without this key it works fine but after including it in Podfile Xcode 7.1 Beta throws these errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_***", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in ***.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_***", referenced from:
_OBJC_CLASS_$_*** in ***.o
objc-class-ref in ***.o
objc-class-ref in ***.o
(maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_***)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_***", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in ***.o
objc-class-ref in ***.o
objc-class-ref in ***.o
"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_***", referenced from:
_OBJC_METACLASS_$_*** in ***.o
(maybe you meant: _OBJC_METACLASS_$_***)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Does your pod include/depend on any static libraries?

Comment: @johnpatrickmorgan This pod depends on another pods

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem... (see [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34909389/cocoapods-use-frameworks-prevents-xcode-from-linking-libraries))

Comment: @shmim I fixed it by moving development pod to subspec and also I removed private headers and specified only public headers.

Comment: how do you specify only public headers?

Comment: @shmim for example if you have the 'ss.' prefix in your subspec then you remove any existed other type headers and left only this:
    ss.public_header_files = [  'Folder/View1.h',
                                           'Folder/View2.h']

Comment: Can you point to a url of a podspec that does this?